# Displaying BLOB fields from SQL Server database with PHP issue

Tags: php

I have a database field in SQL Server 2012 database. They can contain PDF, WORD, Excel or image files. My Blob field type is varbinary(max). My code works fine using ColdFusion, however I have tried to convert it to PHP and it doesn't seem to be working. Below is the code I am using. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?
The example below is just for a word document and when the Word application is launched, I get a "File Conversion" dialog box asking me to select the encoding that makes the document readable none of which makes any difference. The preview window shows a bunch of garbage.

```
<?PHP
$aserverName = "SQ-ENT12-D01\Dev";
$aconnectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"Event_Registration", "UID"=>$uid, "PWD"=>$pwd, "CharacterSet"=>"UTF-8");
$aconn = sqlsrv_connect( $aserverName, $aconnectionInfo);
//  Get the record where the binary data is 
$GetBlobSQL = "select * from Congress where Congress_ID = 102";
$GetBlob = sqlsrv_query($aconn, $GetBlobSQL, array(), array('Scrollable' => 'buffered'));
$GetBlobRecordCount = sqlsrv_num_rows($GetBlob);
$brec = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $GetBlob, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC, SQLSRV_SCROLL_ABSOLUTE, 0);
$WhatFile = ($brec['Document_Agenda']);
$WhatBlob = ($brec['AD_Agenda']);
$MyExt = substr($WhatFile, -4);
$WhatExt = strtolower($MyExt);
header('Content-type: application/ms-word');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$WhatFile.'"');
echo $WhatBlob;
?>
```

I know the file or data in the database is not corrupted because my original ColdFusion code works fine to retrieve and display the data.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `"CharacterSet"=>"UTF-8"` from the `$aconnectionInfo`. You may be confusing the database and causing conversions to take place that are not needed or desired.

Comment: Sorry, but I get a severe error when I remove that code:     Fatal error: Severe error translating Unicode in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\PHP\eventregistration\ViewTest.php on line 9

Comment: Then try setting it to UTF-16.